# Laravel install freeze at 0%

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

I am trying to create laravel project on Mac. I have php 8.1 and composer 2.5.8.
When I call

```
composer create-project laravel/laravel app-name
```

It freezes at 0% for hours

```
Installing laravel/laravel (v10.2.5)
  - Downloading laravel/laravel (v10.2.5)
```

I tried uninstall and reinstall php and composer, still having same problem.

Comment: Please run `composer diagnose` and append the output to your question. Then re-try the command with first `-v` and if it doesn't reveal enough info `-vv`, then `-vvv` (maxium verbosity). You may already spot some issue there where it hangs. But don't forget to add the composer diagnose details to your question first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved simply by upgrading git!